# Inserting row in Pandas DataFrame with two-key Multi-Index fails

Tags: pandas, dataframe, insert, row, multi-index

Please checkout the following simple scenarios and let me know if I'm doing something wrong, or if this is perhaps a bug in Pandas MultiIndex DataFrames?

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((), names=[ "i1", "i2" ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( index = index, columns = [ "c1", "c2" ] )
df
        c1  c2
i1  i2
```

The result is an empty dataframe with a 2-level multiindex (i1, i2) and 2 columns (c1, c2) as shown above. Now insert the first row into this dataframe:

```
df.loc[ ( "x", "y" ) ] = 1
df
        c1  c2  y
i1  i2          
x       NaN NaN 1.0
```

This result was not expected by me. It inserts a new row (correct) with a new column named "y" (incorrect in my view) using the value that should have been inserted in index i2, and assigning no values to i2, c1, and c2.

Compare this to the similar case of a 1-level MultiIndex:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((), names=[ "i1" ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( index = index, columns = [ "c1", "c2" ] )
df
    c1  c2
i1      

df.loc[ "x" ] = 1, 2
df
    c1  c2
i1      
x   1   2
```

Here we find a new row "x" with the index value in the index, the data values in the columns, and no extra column added.

Or with the even more relevant case of a 3-level MultiIndex:

```
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((), names=[ "i1", "i2", "i3" ] )
df = pd.DataFrame( index = index, columns = [ "c1", "c2" ] )
df
            c1  c2
i1  i2  i3  

df.loc[ ("x", "y", "z") ] = 1, 2
df
            c1  c2
i1  i2  i3      
x   y   z   1   2
```

Also in this case inserting a new row ( "x", "y", "z" ) with the index values in the index, the data values in the columns and and no extra column added.

So why this deviant behavior in the case of a 2-level MultiIndex DataFrame? Note that I found the same behavior when adding the row using pd.concat instead of df.loc.

Note also that only for a 2-level MultiIndex DataFrame the statement:

```
df.loc[ ( "x", "y" ) ] = 1, 2
```

generates a ValueError: "cannot set using a multi-index selection indexer with a different length than the value".

Using Python 3.6 (x64) and Pandas 0.20.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, need `:` for select all columns:

```
df.loc[ ( "x", "y" ), :] = 1
print (df)
       c1  c2
i1 i2        
x  y    1   1
```

---

```
df.loc[ ( "x", "y" ), :] = 1,2
print (df)
       c1  c2
i1 i2        
x  y    1   2
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Do you also know why the df.loc[ tuple, : ] syntax is not needed for in the other cases (1- and 3-level MultiIndex)?